# How to append option tag to select in jqyery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a list and need to add as a option tag to Select tag in jquery:

```
var result = mylist;
 var mySelect = $('#status1');
        $.each(result, function (val, text) {
            mySelect.append(
                $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
            );
        });
```

I have copied this code from web but my result is not key value, just simple list, so how can I six this code?

Comment: can you add `result` op as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use single string and append like below code

```
mySelect.append(
 $('<option value="'+val+'">'+text+'</option>')
);
```